# Excel VBA - Check if a worksheet is protected WITH A PASSWORD

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

We can check if a sheet is protected using ProtectContents property. But how check if it is protected with a password?

```
if ws.ProtectContents then
    ''do something
end if
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't believe there is a direct way of doing this by way of a property. Alternatively, though, you could attempt to unprotect the worksheet with a blank password and catch the error should it fail:

```
Function isSheetProtectedWithPassword(ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    If ws.ProtectContents Then
        On Error GoTo errorLabel
        ws.Unprotect ""
        ws.Protect
    End If
errorLabel:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then isSheetProtectedWithPassword = True
End Function
```

You can call this like:

```
isSheetProtectedWithPassword(Worksheets("Sheet1"))
```

And it will return `True` or `False`

Comment: Thank you JNevill.

Comment: I think you need an 'else isSheetProtectedWithPassword = false' at the end...?

Comment: Hi @user3617389. The default for a boolean is `FALSE` so it's unnecessary. If you want to be explicit about it though, then not only will you need that `else` you will also  need to add `isSheetProtectedWithPassword = false` after the `End If` (A line it will only reach if the contents are NOT protected and the error isn't raised.

Answer (score 3):

To check for password protection one needs to try to unprotect the sheet and after that to protect it again (if it was not password protected), but at that point it **looses all the protection settings** the user had made. Like *Allow PivotTables*, *Allow Formatting Cells* and so on.
So one has to read the settings of the sheet first and when protecting it, applying the settings again.
Protection also means not only *protectcontents* but also *protectobject* and *protectscenarios*.
And if it is a Chart Sheet, it also needs a different procedure to check.
I spend som hours to create a macro which can do all this for ALL Sheets (even for **Chart Sheets**).

```
 Sub Run_CheckSheetPasswordProtection()
    'execudes the Function CheckSheetPasswordProtection
    'to detect if a sheet (Worksheet or Chart Sheet) is protected, password protected or not protected
    'protection setting of that sheet will remain the same after checking (other, simpler, macros will not take car for this)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Variant 'variant is needed to handle Worksheets AND Chart Sheets
    Dim sh As Variant
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or use: Workbooks("Name of my Workbook")
    
    '***check one sheet*****
'    'adjust your worksheet you want to test here
'    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
'
'    MsgBox ws.Name & ":     " & CheckSheetPasswordProtection(ws)
    
    
    
    '****check all sheets of a workbook**********
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        'write ansers to the Immediate Window
        Debug.Print sh.Name & ":     " & CheckSheetPasswordProtection(sh)
    Next sh
End Sub


Function CheckSheetPasswordProtection(YourSheet As Variant) As String
    'check if worksheets are protected with a password
    'doesn't destroy the previous protection settings of that sheet
    Dim ws As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ProtectionResult As String
    
    'Settings of the sheet
    Dim sDrawingObjects As Boolean
    Dim sContents As Boolean
    Dim sScenarios As Boolean
    Dim sUserInterfaceOnly As Boolean
    Dim sAllowFormattingCells As Boolean
    Dim sAllowFormattingColumns As Boolean
    Dim sAllowFormattingRows As Boolean
    Dim sAllowInsertingColumns As Boolean
    Dim sAllowInsertingRows As Boolean
    Dim sAllowInseringHyperlinks As Boolean
    Dim sAllowDeletingColumns As Boolean
    Dim sAllowDeletingRows As Boolean
    Dim sAllowSorting As Boolean
    Dim sAllowFiltering As Boolean
    Dim sAllowUsingPivotTables As Boolean
    Dim sEnableSelection As Integer ' 0   Anything can be selected, -4142   Nothing can be selected, 1   Only unlocked cells can be selected.
    Dim sEnableOutlining As Boolean
    
    Set ws = YourSheet
    
    
        '***********if it is a worksheet**************
        If TypeName(ws) = "Worksheet" Then
        
            'check protection settings of the sheet
            sDrawingObjects = ws.ProtectDrawingObjects
            sContents = ws.ProtectContents
            sScenarios = ws.ProtectScenarios
            sUserInterfaceOnly = ws.ProtectionMode
            sAllowFormattingCells = ws.Protection.AllowFormattingCells
            sAllowFormattingColumns = ws.Protection.AllowFormattingColumns
            sAllowFormattingRows = ws.Protection.AllowFormattingRows
            sAllowInsertingColumns = ws.Protection.AllowInsertingColumns
            sAllowInsertingRows = ws.Protection.AllowInsertingRows
            sAllowInseringHyperlinks = ws.Protection.AllowInsertingHyperlinks
            sAllowDeletingColumns = ws.Protection.AllowDeletingColumns
            sAllowDeletingRows = ws.Protection.AllowDeletingRows
            sAllowSorting = ws.Protection.AllowSorting
            sAllowFiltering = ws.Protection.AllowFiltering
            sAllowUsingPivotTables = ws.Protection.AllowUsingPivotTables
            sEnableSelection = ws.EnableSelection
            sEnableOutlining = ws.EnableOutlining
            
            If ws.ProtectContents Or ws.ProtectDrawingObjects Or ws.ProtectScenarios Then
                ProtectionResult = "Protected"
            
                On Error Resume Next
                ws.Unprotect Password:=""
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ProtectionResult = "PASSWORD protected"
                Else 'if sheet was not protected with password, protect it again with its previous setting
                    ws.Protect _
                    Password:="", _
                    DrawingObjects:=sDrawingObjects, _
                    Contents:=sContents, _
                    Scenarios:=sScenarios, _
                    AllowFormattingCells:=sAllowFormattingCells, _
                    AllowFormattingColumns:=sAllowFormattingColumns, _
                    AllowFormattingRows:=sAllowFormattingRows, _
                    AllowInsertingColumns:=sAllowInsertingColumns, _
                    AllowInsertingRows:=sAllowInsertingRows, _
                    AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=sAllowInseringHyperlinks, _
                    AllowDeletingColumns:=sAllowDeletingColumns, _
                    AllowDeletingRows:=sAllowDeletingRows, _
                    AllowSorting:=sAllowSorting, _
                    AllowFiltering:=sAllowFiltering, _
                    AllowUsingPivotTables:=sAllowUsingPivotTables, _
                    UserInterfaceOnly:=sUserInterfaceOnly
                
                    ws.EnableSelection = sEnableSelection
                    ws.EnableOutlining = sEnableOutlining
                End If 'checking for password (error)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else 'if worksheet is not protected
                ProtectionResult = "No Protection"
            End If 'if protected
            
        
        Else '*************if it is a chart*************** If TypeName(ws) = "Chart"
            'check protection settings of the sheet
            sDrawingObjects = ws.ProtectDrawingObjects
            sContents = ws.ProtectContents
            
            'if chart is protected
            If ws.ProtectContents Or ws.ProtectDrawingObjects Then
                ProtectionResult = "Protected"
            
                On Error Resume Next
                ws.Unprotect Password:=""
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ProtectionResult = "PASSWORD protected"
                Else 'if sheet was not protected with password, protect it again with its previous setting
                    ws.Protect _
                    Password:="", _
                    DrawingObjects:=sDrawingObjects, _
                    Contents:=sContents
                End If 'checking for password (error)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else 'if worksheet is not protected
                ProtectionResult = "No Protection"
            End If 'if protected
            
        
        End If 'Worksheet or Chart
        CheckSheetPasswordProtection = ProtectionResult

End Function
```