# How to create code to detect if any Sheet is protected?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the logic of my code:

```
If <any sheets protected> Then
   Msgbox "There's some sheets protected"
else
   Msgbox "No sheets are protected"
end if
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA - Check if a worksheet is protected WITH A PASSWORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874165/excel-vba-check-if-a-worksheet-is-protected-with-a-password)

Comment: No, I mean a code to check if any sheets are protected. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether any sheets are protected you can use the below code.

```
Sub ProtectCheck()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
ProtectCount = 0
For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Ws.ProtectContents = True Then
        ProtectCount = ProtectCount + 1
    End If
Next Ws

If ProtectCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Sheets are protected", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox ProtectCount & " sheet(s) are protected", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```