# How To Un-Protect Workbook With Password, Run Code, Re-Protect Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro that

1. unprotects entire workbook with the password "test"
2. runs code in the middle
3. re-protects with a password.
4. displays a "completed" message indicating the macro ran properly.

If the password is incorrect, the macro should display "error-password incorrect".

I do not get an error entering the correct password, but the code in the middle doesn't run and the workbook isn't re-protected. Yet I get a message saying "completed". I should only get a "completed" message if the password is correct, the rest of the macro runs and the workbook is re-protected with the password.

```vb
Dim S As Object
Dim pWord1 As String
pWord1 = InputBox("Enter password")
If pWord1 = "" Then Exit Sub
For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    On Error GoTo errorTrap1
    wSheet.Unprotect Password:=pWord1
Next wSheet
MsgBox "Completed."
Exit Sub
errorTrap1:
    MsgBox "Error-Password Incorrect"
    Exit Sub
```

The code below is at the end of the macro to re-protect with the password "test".

```vb
    Dim pWord1 As String
    pWord1 = "test"
    If pWord1 = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Protect Password:=pWord1
    Next
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: 7th line has a problem    pword1 not "pword1"

Comment: @ Tin Bum- Thank you sir!  I made the changes and do not get an error.  However, please see my edited question as I re-clarified the body of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach (subject to improvements, but should get you started)

Some suggestions:

- Indent your code
- Try to set the variables initializations like the internal password at the begining of the code
- Name your variables to something readable
- Use functions and subprocedures to execute code in chunks and it'd be easier to debud

**Code**

```
Public Sub CheckProtect()   

    Dim userPassword As String
    Dim internalPassword As String
    
    ' Set internal password to force protection
    internalPassword = "test"
    
    ' Get password from user
    userPassword = InputBox("Enter password")
    
    ' If password is empty, exit procedure
    If userPassword = "" Then Exit Sub ' I'd alert the user at least....
    
    ' Check each sheet in current workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    For Each targetSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Validate if sheet if sheet is protected and password is valid
        Dim passwordIsValid As Boolean
        passwordIsValid = isWorksheetUnprotected(targetSheet, userPassword)
        If Not passwordIsValid Then
            ' Exit for is password is not valid
            Exit For
        End If
    Next targetSheet
    
    
    Select Case passwordIsValid
    Case True
        ' Show message if all sheets were unprotected
        MsgBox "Unprotection completed."
    Case False
        ' Show error password didn't match
        MsgBox "Error-Password Incorrect"
    End Select
    
    ' Run code in "the middle"
    If passwordIsValid Then
        ' Do stuff
        ' INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
        MsgBox "DoStuff"
    End If

    ' Protect all sheets
    For Each targetSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        targetSheet.Protect passWord:=internalPassword
    Next targetSheet
    
End Sub

' Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40874679/1521579
Private Function isWorksheetUnprotected(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, ByVal passwordString As String) As Boolean
    Dim unprotected As Boolean
    If targetSheet.ProtectContents Then
        On Error GoTo errorLabel
        targetSheet.Unprotect passwordString
        unprotected = True
    Else
        unprotected = True
    End If
errorLabel:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then Exit Function
    
    isWorksheetUnprotected = unprotected

End Function
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Wow, wow, wow.  That was brilliant!  I had to move the message boxes around and it took forever (like 15-20 seconds) to run the entire macro but it worked!  Thank you so much sir!

Comment: Sorry I forgot.  How do I prevent locked cells from being selected?

Comment: Use the enableselection property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.enableselection

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple schema you can use in a variety of ways.

```
Function SetProtection(ByVal Pw As String, _
                       Optional ByVal Protect As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    ' 125
    ' return Not True if incorrect password was entered
    
    Dim Ws      As Worksheet
    Dim Pword   As String
    
    Pword = InputBox("Enter password")
    SetProtection = True
    If StrComp(Pword, Pw, vbBinaryCompare) Then
        MsgBox "The password you entered is incorrect.", _
               vbCritical, "Access denied"
        SetProtection = False
    Else
        For Each Ws In Worksheets
            With Ws
                .Unprotect Pw
                If Protect Then
                    Debug.Print "protecting"
                    .Protect Password:=Pw, _
                             DrawingObjects:=True, _
                             Contents:=True, _
                             Scenarios:=True, _
                             UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
                             AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
                             AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
                             AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
                             AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
                             AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
                             AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=False, _
                             AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
                             AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
                             AllowSorting:=False, _
                             AllowFiltering:=False, _
                             AllowUsingPivotTables:=False
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

The function will compare the password entered by the user with the password supplied in the function call. If it's not the same the function will return False. Else it will remove the protection on all sheets.

If the optional argument *Protect* is *True* or omitted the function will continue to reapply protection. I have intentionally listed all properties so that you can see what is being done and easily make the changes you may want. You can remove those that don't take your fancy and Excel will use its defaults. However, I draw your attention to the property *UserInterFaceOnly* which is set to True. This means that whatever protection is applied doesn't apply to VBA. VBA can make change but the user can't. This property remains in force until the workbook is closed. It can't be saved. So you can call the procedure once and let your code work freely. Or you can call the code like `SetProtection "test", False` which will not reapply protection and call `SetProtection "test"` later again and apply the specified protection.

And this is how you might integrate the function in your project.

```
Private Sub Test_Pw()

    Dim Pw As String
    Pw = "test"
    
    If SetProtection(Pw) Then
        MsgBox "Execute your code here"
    End If
End Sub
```

As you see, the code you don't wont to run will be skipped if the function doesn't return True, which it only does if the correct password was entered.

Comment: Thank you!  So would I add the function coding above at the beginning of the macro, then place my code I want to run after it (if the password is correct), then add code to protect the workbook at the end of the macro (whether password is correct or incorrect)?

Comment: Try to think differently:- Your code is in the `Sub Test_Pw()`. That code calls the function `SetProtection` before it does anything else. And if the function doesn't return "True" it will never do anything else. Only if the function returns True the MsgBox will be shown. In your project there will be no MsgBox. Instead, whatever the user started to do will be executed. In your sample code that is `MsgBox "Completed."` (also a MsgBox haha).

Comment: Thank you so much!